# How to turn off this green highlights on html string in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

[image]

As shown clearly in the picture. As long as there is a closed tag, the green backgrounds comes out.

It is very annoying and can hardly provide any help.

Comment: Which scheme you have set?

Comment: there is a typo in your code on line 2 there is missing a `<` for `li>`. Not solving your problem but maybe solving problems with your project :D

Comment: @SebastianBrosch That is intended for your information about the problem :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This green background indicates **Injected language fragment**.

> It is very annoying and can hardly provide any help.

It is like that because of your editor color schema -- your HTML tags have own background which overrides Language Injection background color and creates such visual mess.

You can:

- either disable such injections at all at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`
- or just remove color for them at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General --> Code | Injected language fragment`