# How to disable code highlighting in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I started coding in PHP on PhpStorm and I have this permanent highlight that bothers me and I can't find how to turn it off.

[image: Highlighting in PhpStorm]

I just search on internet but find nothing specific. Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: It's a Language Injection fragment. It is used to show that you have another language (HTML in this case) injected in your string. Quite useful. It just stands out a bit too much on dark theme (it is much better on a light one). Plus, PHP variables there have a different background, which makes it look like a mess TBH (but that's because you are using string concatenation - try HEREDOC perhaps). Anyway: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/40418996/783119 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/30784708/783119 -- see which one suits you better.

Comment: The information on how to configure your IDE should be available in the documentation of your IDE. There is no need to search the internet (and it's that large it certainly can only ever lead to minuscule results and requires research otherwise), searching in the appropriate documentation looks of much more benefit to me. Try that first. Then provide reference where it does not match your expectation or use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing one long print, PHP developers usually do something like close the PHP tag early with a curly bracket open such as:

```php
<?php foreach($items as $item) { ?>
    <div>
        <h1>
            <?= htmlspecialchars($item['title'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5) ?>
        </h1>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Then you'd use another PHP tag to end the open curly bracket.

I should also comment that HTML Id's should not contain spaces: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes:the-id-attribute

> When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's tree and must contain at least one character. *The value must not contain any ASCII whitespace.*

(emphasis mine)

For instances where you don't want to print it immediately, and instead get it back as a string, you can use the same approach in combination with [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), by surrounding it with [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_clean()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Comment: Please put some effort into answers with code suggestions so that they are safe to use. just edited the fragment. Take care on injection issues and forgotten encoding at the relevant places. Thanks!